# Index will not show up in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, indexing

I am new to LaTeX and still on the steep learning curve. I am writing some documentation for a school project which has a bibliography and an index, using ShareLaTeX. I am having difficulty getting the index to show in the table of contents. This bare-bones code sample illustrates my problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\chapter{Introduction}
Some random \index{random} text \index{stuff!text} about fact \cite{fact}.
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\chapter{Main}
\lipsum[6]
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{fact}
    Factual stuff,
    \emph{The types of Facts}. \\
    XXXX, Publisher
    \end{thebibliography}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage} %Line 1

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index} %Line 2
\printindex
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\end{document}
```

If I change Line 1 to `\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}}` then the index shows up in the table of contents, however I want to ensure the index starts on an odd page. I have tried using the `hyperref` package but doing this with the package:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
```

seems to have no effect. I've been looking all over the internet for an answer and I haven't found it. I would appreciate any help and if you need more info please let me know I will do my best :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Do you want all chapters to start on odd pages?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I do, I'd also like the index to start on an odd page (as long as that does not break typesetting convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have chapters start on odd pages, you can add `twoside,openright` to the options of the class. This will change the layout to fit twosided printing, and cause all chapters to start on a right/recto/odd pages.

To add bibliography and index to the ToC, you can add

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

to the preamble. `nottoc` means that the ToC itself does not end up in the ToC.

Also, I just noticed that the index does not seem to start on an odd page even with `twoside,openright`, add a `\cleardoublepage` just before `\printindex` to take care of that. Complete code example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}
Some random \index{random} text \index{stuff!text} about fact \cite{fact}.


\chapter{Main}
\lipsum[6]



\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{fact}
    Factual stuff,
    \emph{The types of Facts}. \\
    XXXX, Publisher
    \end{thebibliography}

\cleardoublepage\printindex


\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the `twoside, openright` tip, that's very efficient. Secondly, when I tried the source code you provided in ShareLaTeX,the index did not show up in the ToC. Should I try another distribution of LaTeX (I have a portable version of MikTeX as a backup)?

Comment: @neoTexDalus Please try in MikTeX. It works fine for me with TeX Live 2013, while ShareLaTeX uses TeX Live 2011. I guess that there is something that has changed between the two versions.

Comment: @neoTexDalus By the way, I just noticed that the index does not start on an odd page even with `twoside,openright`, so add a `\cleardoublepage` just before `\printindex` to fix that (I've updated my answer.)

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. I tried it in TexLive 2013 (MikTex had some problem with missing fonts or something) and it worked just beautifully. I think maybe ShareLaTeX isn't doing either enough or misordered runs of pdfLaTeX, BibTex and MakeIndex. I'll keep using it and just compile using TexLive 2013 when I need to submit. As a note to you and others I found an `emptypage` package  which combined with your suggestion is a more efficient way to get `\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. When I added the `tocbibind` package as per above, it threw the following error: Option clash for package tocbibind.

Comment: @SuperAl That means you've already loaded the package (or the documentclass, or some other package, loads it), but with more/different options the first time than the second time.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No, I did not already load it. It is a `memoir` thing. That package does not work with `memoir`. What is the solution for that document class then?

Comment: @SuperAl Well yes, as stated in the manual, `memoir` has the same features as several packages, including `tocbibind`. So you don't have to do anything, the bibliography and index shows up in the ToC by default. (E.g. try the example in my answer, but with `memoir` as the class, and without `tocbibind`.) To get the `nottoc` feature, use `\tableofcontents*` instead of `\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score -1):

Add toc request when you make the index:

```
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]
```

Comment: What package is required that provides the `intoc` option to `\makeindex`? Ahhh, [`imakeidx`](//ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx). Why don't you include that in your answer?