# Is there a way to avoid writing "term \index{term}" when creating an index?

Tags: indexing, makeindex

The standard way of creating an index is by writing something like,

"term \index{term}"

[Index will not show up in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144494/index-will-not-show-up-in-table-of-contents)

> Some random \index{random} text \index{stuff!text} about fact
>   \cite{fact}.

It would have been much more efficient and more elegant to write only

"\index{term}"

The problem is that, Latex will not show "term" in the output pdf if only \index{term} was written.

Is there anyway to change this behavior?

Comment: Not identical, but it should help: [Automatic index entry for multiword terms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470544/579).  By the way, why the tag [bibliographies]?  They''re not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node that you should do

```
term\index{term}
```

or some recommend

```
\index{term}term
```

never

```
term \index{term}
```

Or you may get a page break after `term` and the index will refer to the following page. The choice of which of the first forms to use depends if your "term" can be hyphenated and what you want to do if the page break occurs at the hyphen, index the start or end of the term.

You can define

```
\newcommand\zz[1]{#1\index{#1}}
```

then use

```
\zz{term}
```

If that is more convenient.